# Residual Error Increases with Signal Amplitude

Tags: error

A 1-dimensional signal $z$ goes through a nonlinear system and is transformed into $y$. To build an inverse model of the nonlinear system, I constructed the Vandermonde feature matrix $Y$ from $y$, which then was used to predict $z$. Since the nonlinear system changes its characteristics with the ambient temperature, I noticed that, as shown in the following plot,
[image: comparison]

- At room temperature, the residual error increases almost linearly with amplitude of $z$. My first question is, is this normal? Are there cases where these two are independent?
- At cold, the residual error increases faster as the amplitude of $z$ reaches beyond a certain level. My second question would be, what may be the underlying cause of this in terms of feature construction? How can I bring it back to the linear relation?

(This may or may not help, but for those interested, the nonlinear system is a Radio Frequency Power Amplifier, and I'm trying to build an inverse model of it. The input signal is a digitally modulated signal in the form of IQ)

Comment: It's not clear what scope you intend to include in "is this normal?" If you mean "does this usually happen for this kind of signal?" --- how are we to know that? You'd need to ask people in the application area who might be familiar with the thing you're measuring. If you mean "is it normal for positive random variables?" then I'd say it's quite common (and in many cases, to be anticipated). Similarly, when you ask " Are there cases where these two are independent?" ... what universe of applications are we including here? ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd)... If you just mean "in this application", then you're probably asking the wrong people. You should also be careful of using a lot of jargon from a different application area (few of us will be familiar with RF power amplifiers); it reduces the likelihood of your question being well understood. It's not clear what you mean by "bring it back" in your last sentence -- what set of things are you including in your considerations? What are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: My first piece of advice is to consider working on the log-scale - at least as far as drawing pictures); it will lead to approximately constant spread for the first case. Questions of underlying causes will come from the physics of the situation (which isn't obvious from your post), but - for example - if there's a more-or-less constant amount of noise in inputs but those inputs are  being amplified to different degrees (producing larger or smaller signal), one would expect the spread to increase along with the signal.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to get some insight that helps me relate to the physics. I'll come back to this post once the cause is identified, hopefully.